# How to identify Mongo Atlas performance issues?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I don't know how to identify Mongo performance issues in a "high traffic project".

It's a MERN stack project where Mongo is deployed on AWS by using [MongoDB Atlas cloud](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database). All queries are run by Heroku server that is running on Performance L-dyno with enabled auto scaling.

There are 2 databases with around 80 collection. 1 collection has around 130k records, 4-5 collections has around 40k-80k records and others have less than 5k records. I tried to test a user flow that generates ~110 mongo queries. I estimate ~110 queries based on all [mongo spans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXOG5.jpg) tracked by DataDog. All these mongo spans have duration between 50ms-500ms in production/development environment. I created a test suite in JMeter where I test this flow with 500 virtual users where ramp-up period is 60s. When I run this test, [mongo spans have extremely long duration >30s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Man3p.jpg) and they cause request timeout errors on the server.

I tried to upgrade the Mongo Atlas environment to M200 (I tried both [General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxUFH.jpg) option and [Local NVMe SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LUaF.jpg)) and I tried M300 as well. It didn't help, mongo's spans duration is too long. When the test was running, I didn't notice any spikes in Mongo Atlas -> Real Time monitor. CPU with Disk Util were under 5%. When I run the test and I see it's failing, I stop the test and check traces in DataDog, there is not more 1000 mongo spans(queries) in DataDog.

When I open [Mongo Atlas Profiling View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzji5.jpg), I can see that queries execution time is a bit slower when test is running, but most of them are missing. Do you know why profiling view is missing some queries and doesn't show slow queries >30s I can see in DataDog?

How is it possible that such as a strong environment M200/M300 is not able to process <50k queries with collections <150k records within one minute?

Do you have any idea how I can identify what's the issue with Mongo server? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7zgi.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RViJI.jpg) are screenshots from Metrics view where you can see some spikes when tests were running on M200 configuration.

There are [3 recommendations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7JFK.jpg) in performance advisor to add an index to 3 collections. Do you think this can be the issue why Mongo server is so slow?

Comment: These can be tough issues to debug, it doesn't look like the recommendations will be particularly impactful to the issue you're seeing (though might be worth doing anyway). How many databases/collections do you have? Mongo doesn't do great when you have thousands of namespaces, in particular the profiler and index recommendations get out of whack. What is the query you issue against `heroku_56jdrn0.pairs`? 

Remember that within node, mongo uses a connection pool - if all connections in that pool are in use, all subsequent operations will be delayed until a connection is free

Comment: If I am not mistaken the screenshots show failovers during your tests. It take some time for the cluster to elect new primary, which would explain delays on application level, and no records in slow log db side. The driver just didn't have a primary to send the request to and start countdown for slow log threshold.  I am sure you are more interested in root cause of the failover, but there is not enough information. M200/M300 are quite pricey tiers. I am sure you are entitled to some hours of Atlas support. I'd advise you to use them.

Comment: @ZackNewsham the screenshots show < 100 connections. M200 limit is 128k. Same applies to RAM and CPU utilisation. If screenshots are accurate, Matt is using a teeny-tiny fraction of resources he pays for.

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm not talking about the mongo server limit on connections, I'm talking about the connection pool applied by the mongo client - it might not be relevant, but the default used to be 5 - and we saw this a lot when that was the default (5 slow aggregations blocking seemingly trivial lookups)

Comment: @ZackNewsham there are 2 databases with around 80 collection. 1 collection has around 130k records, 4-5 collections has around 40k-80k records and others have less than 5k records. If connections in the pool is the issue, shouldn't I see any issues in metrics view?

Comment: @AlexBlex do you mean [this](https://imgur.com/a/sqWRWB7) by failover? It's a time when I changed the cluserter configuration from M50 -> M200. I will use their support for sure, but what kind of information is missing to identify the issue?

Comment: @Matt you wouldn't see anything *much* from the atlas side - you'd potentially see a discrepency between the time your spans take (recorded from the app server) and the time the profiler (in atlas) shows. That number of databases/collections is totally reasonable - so that isn't the problem

Comment: Have you tried `explain` on the mongo queries used during your tests? It may well be related with a missing/partial index? I don't know about Atlas tools, but there was a Mongo Compass client that helped with such performance/index issues.

Comment: @ZackNewsham good point. I believe java driver has 100 connections max by default, but it definitely makes sense to look at the application level. Since re-election was intentional, there is nothing obvious on the metrics. Matt, I assume the second upgrade was around 13:20, right?  The scan&order spike indicates some sub-optimal queries/indexes, yet nothing that would dramatically affect the cluster. If support doesn't help, I'd spin up own cluster to get db logs and correlate them to application logs when timeouts happen. I was referring to logs as the "missing  information".

Comment: @Matt I'd still like to see the query that's using an and from your screenshot, you can also eliminate the connection pool as an issue by changing that to be 1000. This doesn't eliminate the app server as a possible source of the problem but it does eliminate the pool at the very least. What is your app servers CPU looking like during these times? Bson deserialisation isn't free, if your docs are large and you're executing 50k queries in a short period, that may also be contributing to the slowness

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, there was upgrade around 12:30. I run the test again and checked number of connections, there were not more than 88. I added mongo logs to my questions.

Comment: @ZackNewsham I run the test again and checked number of connections, there is not more than 88. The server is on Heroku Performance L-dyno with enabled auto scaling. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/quIHlA9) is the screenshot from dyno load, but it doesn't seem like an to me. I added mongo logs to my questions, but I didn't find anything useful there.

Comment: @murtiko thanks I will need to try it out, but I think some missing indexes shouldn't be an issue if cpu and disk io are under 5% during the test.

Comment: @ZackNewsham I am about to try inceasing pool size to 1000 and let you know the result.

Comment: @ZackNewsham I increased pool size to 10k. when I run the test, the number of connections were around [300](https://imgur.com/a/wq53cHV). Perhaps this was a bottleneck, but even after changing pool size to 10k, the test is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out the issue is with the Heroku server. Even if you use autoscaling with performance dynos, Heroku server is not able to process a lot of requests. You just need to use more dynos. The Heroku server was blocked on load tests. I just don't understand why DataDog shows long mongo spans if mongo queries weren't executed. When I checked mongo logs, the queries are missing.